# How can I match any characters between a period and a semi-colon in Regex?

Tags: regex

How can I match any characters between a period and a semi-colon in Regex, including whitespace, carriage returns, and other periods and special characters including brackets?

For example, given:

```
SomeMethod().AnotherMethod("argument")
      .AnotherMethod(1, "arg");
```

I want to be able to match:

```
.AnotherMethod("argument")
      .AnotherMethod(1, "arg");
```

Comment: Please specify your language/flavor.

Comment: `\.([^;]*);` works per spec... But I beg to ask what happens when you've a `SomeMethod("With (a; Funky', 'arg\"ument");`?

Answer (score 3):

`\.([^;]*);` seems to fit the bill.

Note that the question you asked is probably simpler than what you really need: presumably you want to get a similar result from `SomeMethod().AnotherMethod("foo; bar; and baz").AnotherMethod(1);`, but the regex you've asked for will stop at the first `;`.

Comment: @jimmy_terra: I would recommend using [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr) (or a similar tool) for verifying your regexes in the future. It provides great overview (eg of groups) + great quick reference. It's really an asset (I am a regex beginner too).

Comment: You don't use a dot in your regex, so no "dot matches newline" mode needed. `[^;]` is matching really all characters except ";" including newlines.

Comment: Ha, you're right! I just sorta assumed I had used a dot. I'll edit that out.

Comment: What happens when you've a `SomeMethod("With (a; Funky', 'arg\"ument");`?

Comment: This is nearly working - it doesn't work across lines though, so it picks up `.AnotherMethod(1, "arg");` ok, but not the line above it aswell...

Answer (score 0):

Either `[.](.*?);` or `[.]([^;]*);`.

*`[.]` is just another way to escape the `.` char, traditionally escaped using `\.`*

Comment: That first version will perform much worse than the second on long input strings. I wouldn't recommend it to anyone.

Comment: [.]([^;]*); works but as above, only picks up the second line and doesnt detect carriage returns

Answer (score 0):

`\.([^;]*);` works per your original spec, but you'll quickly run into problems...

In practice you'll need named groups and a recursive regex to parse this properly.

Here's a starting point (in ruby):

```
re = %r{
  (?<sstr>      '(?:[^']|(?<=\\)')*?') {0}                    # single quoted
  (?<dstr>      "(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")*?") {0}                    # double quoted
  (?<nstr>      [^;]*?) {0}                                   # non-string
  (?<arg>       (?:\g<sstr>|\g<dstr>|\g<nstr>|)) {0}          # optional arg
  (?<func>      \s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*\(\s*\g<arg>\s*\)\s*) {0}  # foo(arg)
  (?<chain>     \g<func>(?:\.\g<func>)*) {0}                  # chained foo(arg)
  ^\g<chain>;                                                 # match until ;
}x

pp re.match 'SomeMethod("With (a; Funky\', arg\"ument");'
```

Note that the above is only a partial solution. For instance, it wouldn't cover things like:

```
foo(cond()? 'even' : "more", "; funky")
```

But it'll hopefully get you started in the right direction, if you fail to find a built-in function/argument parser in the language that you're coding into.